# C++, AÑADIR DÍAS DE LA SEMANA A PROGRAMA DE TEMPERATURA

Tags: c++

tengo una dificultad para añadir DÍAS de la semana a un código de un programa de captura de datos,SOLO NECESITO UNA MANERA DE AÑADIR LOS DÍAS LUNES, MARTES...DOMINGO y poder mostrar cuál fue el día más caluroso, agradezco su atención, si me pudieran mandar información o ejemplos lo apreciaría mucho también.

CÓDIGO:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    float temperaturas[7],prom,suma=0.0,max=-99.99;
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
        {
            cout<<"Capture temperatura promedio del día:";
            cin>>temperaturas[i];
            
        }
cout<<endl;     
        cout<<"Orden Ascendente: ";
        for (int i=0;i<7;i++){
                cout<<temperaturas[i]<<" ";
        }
    cout<<endl; 
    cout<<"Orden Descendente: ";
        for (int i=6;i>=0;i--){
                cout<<temperaturas[i]<<" ";
        }   
cout<<endl;     
cout<<"TEMPERATURA MAXIMA: "<<max<<endl;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear tres variables extra

```
float tempMax = 0;
string dia = "";
string dias[7] = {"Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sabado", "Domingo"};
```

Donde `tempMax` servirá como bandera almacenando la temperatura máxima alcanzada en los días de la semana, la segunda (`dia`) almacenara el día de la temperatura máxima y por último la el arreglo `dias` que contendrá cada uno de los días de la semana.

Entonces en tu primer ciclo simplemente agregarías las variables que creamos de la siguiente manera:

```
for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
{
    cout<<"Capture temperatura promedio del día " + dias[i] + ": " ;
    cin>>temperaturas[i];
    if (temperaturas[i] > tempMax) {
        tempMax = temperaturas[i];
        dia = dias[i];
    }
}
```

Al finalizar el ciclo puedes imprimirlo por consola:

```
cout << "Día más caluroso: " + dia + " con una temperatura de: " + to_string(tempMax) << endl;
```

Se agrego la función to_string que permite parsear un número a string la función se puede usar con la librería que tienes incluida al principio (`#include <iostream>`)